# IntelliJ IDEA can not resolve maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA stuck in "Reading .../pom.xml"

I changed my hosts file, added 127.0.0.1 localhost, couldn't work

I deleted IntelliJ IDEA config directory, reinstalled IntelliJ IDEA , couldn't work

I reintalled maven, couldn't work

I use IntelliJ's inner maven version instead of the download one, couldn't work

I changed these two configuration settings in maven, still couldn't work
[image]

The error shows in IDEA log file:

```
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndexException: Cannot read index.properties file
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.<init>(MavenIndex.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.load(MavenIndices.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.<init>(MavenIndices.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.ensureInitialized(MavenIndicesManager.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getIndicesObject(MavenIndicesManager.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.ensureIndicesExist(MavenIndicesManager.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenProjectIndicesManager$3.run(MavenProjectIndicesManager.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:277)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:291)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.access$700(Alarm.java:344)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:395)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:242)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ifly\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\Maven\Indices\Index0\index.properties (系统找不到指定的文件。)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.<init>(MavenIndex.java:116)
    ... 23 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

try removing .IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\Maven\ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I try removing .IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\Maven\ directory.
But when idea rebuild the directory.there is no index.properties.